# Why isn't it a good idea to open the file before each writing and close it right after each writing?

Tags: c, file, structure

Suppose you are writing a list of names in a file, each name being written in a write command. Why isn't it a good idea to open the file before each writing and close it right after each writing?

Intuitively, I would say that this aproach is a lot more time consuming than writing to a buffer and posteriorly writing to the file. But I'm sure there is a better explanation to that. Can someone enlight me?

Comment: You answered your own question. One of the biggest concerns is the expensive IO task of opening, writing, and closing the same file over and over again

Comment: Why do you think there would be a better explanation? Gross inefficiency is reason enough.

Comment: Way less efficient. Opening and closing are operations that take time. And when you open, the system starts at the beginning of the file so you'd have to do an explicit seek to the end each time before writing the next line.

Comment: Open the file only once.  Perform all the 'writes' then close the file.  This avoid LOTS of wasted time performing the operations needed (for book keeping, etc) to `open write close` the file, in a loop.  Note: that bookkeeping can fail, so dont want to repeatedly perform those operations.  Also that bookkeeping is performed at disk I/O speeds rather than RAM speeds

Answer (score 4):

Let's sum it up:

Opening and closing a file for every single write operation, when many such operations are planned, is a bad idea because:

1. It is terribly inefficient.
2. It requires an extra seek to the end of file in order to append.
3. It forfeits atomicity, meaning that the file may be renamed, moved, deleted, written to, or locked by someone else between the write operations.

Answer (score 1):

Think of all the possible reasons why `fopen` (and related) might fail when you call it even once: the file doesn't exist, your account doesn't have permission to access or create it, another program is using the file exclusively, etc.

If you are repeatedly opening and closing the file for every write operation, this chance of failure increases quite a bit.

Also, there is an overhead associated with acquiring and releasing resources (e.g. files). You'd observe it more if you were acquiring and releasing write access to the file every single time you needed to write.